# How to do database migrations in LoopBack 4

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, loopback4

When the application is in the production stage and it's needed to do changes in tables, I guess doing `automigrate` is out of the question since it deletes all the data of the tables being changed. Doing `autoupdate` would be appropriate, but I'm concerned about scalability. Is it safe to rely on `autoupdate` on a product in the production stage? One advantage of Rails-like migrations is keeping a record of changes to ensure that every instance or environment of the database will be in the exact same schema. Is there any well-developed way to achieve this in LoopBack?

Not only because of this but if it's needed to normalize data during a column change, how would it be done in LoopBack? I didn't see support for this kind of migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hello from the LoopBack team*

> Doing autoupdate would be appropriate, but I'm concerned about scalability. Is it safe to rely on autoupdate on a product in the production stage? One advantage of Rails-like migrations is keeping a record of changes to ensure that every instance or environment of the database will be in the exact same schema. Is there any well-developed way to achieve this in LoopBack?

You are right that running auto-magic database migration (as the one provided by `autoupdate`) on live production data is risky. We are discussing a more robust framework in the GitHub issue [loopback-next#487](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/487), feel free to join the effort! One of the community members mentioned a 3rd-party package [loopback4-migration](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback4-migration), you may want to check it out.

> Not only because of this but if it's needed to normalize data during a column change, how would it be done in LoopBack? I didn't see support for this kind of migration.

I am afraid the current automigrate/autoupdate design does not support custom data transformations as part of database migration. A possible option is to overwrite `app.migrateSchema` to run additional database command before or after the automated migration is executed.

```
class MyApplication extends RepositoryMixin(RestApplication) {
 async migrateSchema(options: SchemaMigrationOptions = {}): Promise<void> {
   // add code to normalize data before column definitions are changed
   await super.migrateSchema(options);
   // add code to normalize data after column definitions were changed
  }
}
```